# How to properly convert between a UTF-8 buffer and a common Delphi string?

Tags: delphi, utf-8, delphi-11-alexandria

I prepared some code snippet from Delphi recommendations, no compiler warnings or implicit casts but the result unsatisfied me.

```
procedure Convert;
type
  TUTF8Buf = array [0 .. 5] of byte;
var
  s: string;
  sutf8: UTF8String; // manageable UTF-8 string
  utf8str: TUTF8Buf; // unmanageable buffer
begin
  utf8str := Default (TUTF8Buf); // utf8str = (0,0,0,0,0,0)
  s := UTF8ArrayToString(utf8str); // s = #0#0#0#0#0#0
  s := 'abc'; // s = 'abc'
  sutf8 := UTF8Encode(s); // sutf8 = 'abc'
  Move(sutf8[1], utf8str[0], Min(Length(sutf8), sizeof(utf8str) - 1)); // utf8str = (97, 98, 99, 0, 0)
  s := UTF8ArrayToString(utf8str); // s = 'abc'#0#0#0
  s := UTF8ToString(sutf8); // s = 'abc'
end;
```

The code works perfectly fine when it is used with the manageable UTF-8 string but always produces trailing zeroes with the unmanageable buffer. What is the proper modern way of handling such buffers?

Answer (score 2):

The `UTF8ArrayToString()` function converts the entire array as a whole, it does not stop if a `$0` byte is encountered. You should use a different routine that lets you specify how many bytes in the array should be converted, such as `Utf8ToUnicode()`, `UnicodeFromLocaleChars()`, or `TEncoding.UTF8.GetChars()`.

That said, the simplest way to deal with UTF-8 is to just use `UTF8String` by itself. The RTL knows how to implicitly convert between `UnicodeString` and `UTF8String`, let it do the work for you. You don't need `UTF8Encode()` and `UTF8Decode()`, as they have been deprecated since 2009.

Comment: UTF8ArrayToString is a `System` module function, when I tried using UTF8Decode, Delphi recommended to use it instead. So I thought that this function works specifically with unmanageable buffers and it looked like it - the code is compiled without warnings or hints, but the result is weird.

Comment: As per using manageable UTF-8 strings instead of buffers I will do it in the future but now I specifically need to pass them to some DLL.

Comment: `TEncoding.UTF8.GetString` also produces trailing zeroes. So looks like there is no a safe way, just `length`s `byte`s and `SizeOf`s

Comment: @Molochnik You're right, I couldn't find `UTF8ArrayToString()` as a system function at first, but I just did. I have updated my answer. In any case, if you give any conversion function an array with trailing zeros, and don't tell it a length that omits the zeros, then you are going to get trailing zeros in the output. Which is to be expected, since U+0000 is a valid Unicode codepoint, after all.

Comment: With every new Delphi version some UTF-8 routines are changed removed or became obsolete. Codegear made so much efforts moving to UTF-16 in 2009 sacrificing tons of the old code and all was in vain, with UTF-8 non localized codes would have worked as before, Go designers in 2009 were more farsighted

Comment: @Molochnik they made the correct decision. Windows was the only platform supported at the time, and the Win32 API is mostly UTF-16, very little of it uses UTF-8. And then later, other platforms added are also mostly UTF-16, too. UTF-8 is good for storage and communication, not as good for in-memory processing. UTF-16 is easier to handle. That is why most languages standard on it

Answer (score 0):

Chars in `UTF8String` have variable lengths, but `#$00`-`#$7F` never appear in multi-byte chars. So, just like `AnsiString`, you can determine the length by scanning for `#00`. `StrLen` (moved to the `AnsiString` unit in recent versions) does it for you.

```
function ToUTF8String(const Buf): UTF8String;
var 
  len: Integer;
begin
  len := StrLen(PAnsiChar(@Buf));
  SetLength(Result, len);
  if len > 0 then Move(Buf, Result[1]);
end;
```

Note: Should work but I haven't tested it.